# edit file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an error in my program it can't edit file. Where I `var_dump($this->data[data])` data it found but not save in database

This is my controller

```
function edit_kegiatan($id='')
    {
        //set validation properties
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tanggal_kegiatan', 'Tanggal', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_kegiatan', 'Judul Berita', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'required');

        $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
        //run validation
        // jika dia ingin update data atau form validation error

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $this->load->model('mkegiatan');
            $config['upload_path']      = './images/';
            $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']         = '100000';
            $config['max_width']        = '10240';
            $config['max_height']       = '7680';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))     
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $datafoto=$this->upload->data();
                $nm_file =$datafoto['file_name'];
                $data = array(
                    'tanggal_kegiatan'  => $this->input->post('tanggal_kegiatan'),
                    'nama_kegiatan'     => $this->input->post('nama_kegiatan'),
                    'content'           => $this->input->post('content'),
                    'image'             => $nm_file
                );
                $this->mkegiatan->update_kegiatan($id,$data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateSuccessMessage('Data berhasil diupdate'));
                redirect(site_url('admin/kegiatan'));
            }
        }

        $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
        $this->data['data'] = $this->mkegiatan->get_by_id($id);
        $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('admin/kegiatan/edit_kegiatan', $this->data, true);
        $this->load->view('template/wrapper/admin/wrapper_ukm',$this->data);

    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: at first we want error message, at second we want # of line, where it fires

Comment: you can get this issue by print your query in model. may be query is not correct.